# Is ggplot2 v2.2.0 behaving differently when using geom_point?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I recently updated to version 2.2.0 of ggplot2 but noticed differences with the previous version when running my code. 
Previously, I was using the code below to plot borderless circles (shape 21) with the first `geom_point` line. Subsequently, using the second `geom_point` line I would use a black border to outline specific circles (in this case, anything with `$disp > 200`). Here's a snapshot from my own data:

[image]

However with the new ggplot2 I'm not able to plot bordeless circles and mark others as before.

Are there any workarounds?

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=mpg))
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(fill=hp, size=cyl), shape=21, col=NA)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="red")
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=mtcars[which(mtcars$disp>200),], aes(size=cyl), shape=21, col="Black")
gg
```

[image]

```
gg <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=mpg))
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(fill=hp, size=cyl), shape=21)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="red")
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=mtcars[which(mtcars$disp>200),], aes(size=cyl), shape=21)
gg
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I tried adding `stroke=0` as per the comments below but it seems to ignore it altogether. That is, i stil get the same as my last image.

```
rm(gg)
gg <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=mpg))
gg<- gg + geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(fill=hp, size=cyl), shape=21, stroke = 0)
gg
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="red")
gg
gg<- gg + geom_point(data=mtcars[which(mtcars$disp>200),], aes(size=cyl), shape=21, stroke = 0)
gg
```

Testing further, if i switch stroke=2, i do get a change in border thickness:
[image]

So it seems to be ignoring only when i set it to 0.

Comment: try setting stroke=0. Curiously lwd=0 makes the points very small

Comment: @baptiste : doesn't make a difference using this: gg<- gg + geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(fill=hp, size=cyl, stroke = 0), shape=21)

Comment: You have to put the `stroke = 0` outside the `aes`. E.g.: `geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(fill=hp, size=cyl), shape=21, stroke = 0)`

Comment: @h3rm4n: I am adding stroke=0 outside the aes() but i still get a black outline around my circles - see updated OP. Could something else be going on?

Comment: with respect to stroke=0 inside or outside aes(), this confuses me: the R Documentation (?geom_point) under Aesthetics states "geom_point understands the following aesthetics (required aesthetics are in bold): ... stroke". Doesn't that mean it should go inside the aes()? Perhaps a topic for another question.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1757) is related.  If I read things correctly, we would expect to be able to use `stroke = NA` to get rid of the stroke but it doesn't work due to something in grid.

Answer (score 0):

As I have said in the comments, you have to put `stroke = 0` outside of the `aes`. The downside of this is that the legend for `size` will not show. You can see the effect by using:

```
gg <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = gear, y = mpg))
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(fill = hp, size = cyl), shape = 21, stroke = 0)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red")
gg <- gg + geom_point(data = mtcars[which(mtcars$disp>200),], aes(size = cyl), shape = 21, stroke = 0)
gg
```

this results in:

[image]

You can repair the legend by using `override.aes`:

```
gg <- gg + guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(stroke = 0.5)))
gg
```

this results in:

[image]

Comment: presumably the second layer was meant to have a stroke?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround would be to map `color` to the same variable as `fill` for the overall points layer but use the default color of black for the subset of interest.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = gear, y = mpg, size = cyl)) +  
    geom_point(aes(fill = hp, color = hp), shape = 21) + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red") + 
    scale_color_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red") + 
    geom_point(data = mtcars[mtcars$disp>200,], shape = 21)
```